# Breaking from parts of a loop in python, but continuing with the rest

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

Assume we have a text file named `MyFile.txt`, which is structured like this:

```
some info
some more info
Unit: Unit1
E 32 5 5 ee
R 123 534 345 543 634 634 345
R 543 634 634 345 123 534 345
```

We want to store data from the lines that start with `R` in a list called `Data` (which will later be converted to a dataframe), and we want to add the "Unit name" (`Unit1` here) to the end of each line, so that the end result would look like this:

```
print(Data)

R 123 534 345 543 634 634 345 Unit1
R 543 634 634 345 123 534 345 Unit1
```

The following function `fn` will loop through each line, store lines that start with `R` in `UN`, store the word `Unit1` in a new list called `UN`, and append it to the end of each line:

```
UN = []
Data = []
def fn(FileName):
    with open(FileName, "r") as fi:
        for line in fi:
            if line.startswith("Unit"):
                UN.append(line.split()[1])
            elif line.startswith("R"):
                Data.append(line.split()[0:] + list(UN))
```

In the event that our text file has two lines that start with `Unit`:

```
some info
some more info
Unit: Unit1
E 32 5 5 ee
Unit: Unit1
R 123 534 345 543 634 634 345
R 543 634 634 345 123 534 345
```

The function above would append `Unit1` to the end of each line twice, resulting in this:

```
R 123 534 345 543 634 634 345 Unit1 Unit1
R 543 634 634 345 123 534 345 Unit1 Unit1
```

How can we stop the loop after it finds the unit name one time, but continue with the rest of the loop so that it only appends the unit name once?

Comment: You could add the last item of your list `UN`, e.g.  `Data.append(line.split()[0:] + UN[-1])`

Comment: If you only want a single Unit value, why in the world are you appending it to a list?  Just store the value directly in a variable.  Multiple occurrences of "Unit:" would simply overwrite previous values.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I have tried that, but I get the error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: @jasonharper it is part of a larger program i am working on I have a valid reason for it

Comment: You could just check if it is already there: `if line.split()[1] not in UN: UN.append(line.split()[1])`. Or if order is not important, make `UN` a `set`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp could you demonstrate what you mean in an answer? I may be implementing it incorrectly but havent gotten this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are using list to store the unit? would both units be the same? in this case instead of storing the unit in a list you can simply store it in a variable, if your loop comes across it a second time it just overwrites the variable so you are still only appending one unit.

```
UN = ''
Data = []
def fn(FileName):
    with open(FileName, "r") as fi:
        for line in fi:
            if line.startswith("Unit"):
                UN = line.split()[1]
            elif line.startswith("R"):
                Data.append(line.split()[0:] + [UN])
```

if you want to make sure you only pick the first entry of unit you can add an additional if statement to check if 'UN' is empty or not.

Comment: when I run this, I get the error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`. And yes there is a reason i am storing the unit name more than once, I will be using this to iterate over multiple text files from different units

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the extra `if` statement, as menitioned by you and @JohnnyMopp though, thanks!

Comment: Edited the code to account for the TypeError, making the string a list when concatenating